# Do index type (unique and non-unique) affect table locking as result of DML?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

If there is an FK in child table that is not indexed then any updates to PK of the parent table locks entire child table, unless FK in child table is indexed.

My question is that if we want to prevent whole table lock then is the FK index has to be unique? Or It doesn't matter if the index is unique or non-unique?

Comment: Shouldn't that depend on what the FK column has or will have? If it's going to have unique data, you should create unique index. If not create regular.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I want to know if index being unique or non-unique affects the locking behaviour?

Comment: It can be unique, non-unique or even a compound index (if the FK column is listed 1st).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index doesn't have to be unique. It can be a regular or compound one.

The purpose of the index on a foreign key is to avoid full table locking while doing:

1. Delete in parent table
2. update of primary key column

and is useful while doing joins by avoiding Full Table scans.

See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_foreign_key_indexing.htm